# JavaScript license information for merged and minified file

Tags: javascript, licensing, minify

I would like to add my own copyright statement and license text on top of a minified file, that contains some third party libraries as well as my own code. Can I do this without worries, if I keep the license comments of the third party libraries (all MIT license) intact?

So, for clarification, my final file would look somewhat like this:

```
/* my license */
/* underscore license */
[ ... minified underscore code ...]
/* jquery license */
[ ... minified jquery code ...]
[ ... my minified code ...]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both underscore and jQuery are licensed under the [MIT license](http://opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php), so as long as you keep those licenses intact in the code, you should be fine.

[IANAL disclaimer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IANAL)

Comment: Thanks! Is the order in which I put the license information correct? Is it ok to put mine on the very top or should I put, where my actual code begins?

Comment: As far as I know, unless the owners of the third-party libraries explicitly state how to credit them, the order in which the licenses appear is not important. To me, the way you ordered it makes the most sense. If you are not confident about it, you can always mention the libraries you used at the top of the file.